# DataGrid fetching particular row on dropdownselectedindex value change event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datagridview

Im working on one small project.Using Datagrid in that

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgShowTiming"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              OnItemCreated="dgShowTiming_ItemCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="HOUR">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShowTimingsHours"
                                  runat="server"
                                  CssClass="field1"
                                  DataSource="<%#Hour()%>"
                                  DataTextField="Hours"
                                  DataValueField="Hours">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="MINUTE">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShowTimingsminutes"
                                  runat="server"
                                  CssClass="field1"
                                  DataSource="<%#Minute()%>"
                                  DataTextField="Minutes"
                                  DataValueField="Minutes">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="AM/PM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShowTimingAMPM"
                                  runat="server"
                                  CssClass="field1"
                                  onchange="GetCountryDetails()">
                    <asp:ListItem>AM</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>PM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShowTimingDescription"
                                  runat="server"
                                  DataSource="<%#Description()%>"
                                  DataTextField="ShowTimeDesc"
                                  DataValueField="ShowTimeDescID"
                                  CssClass="field1">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Tax Details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRowID"
                           runat="Server"
                           Text="View"
                           Style="cursor: pointer;"
                           onclick="FilmTaxDetailsOpen(this);"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

So Now My problem in this Grid is i have to on selectedindexchange value of dropdown ddlShowTimingAMPM i want to change the description as NOON or morning or evening..Problem im facing is how to fetch the values of 3 dropdownlist selected , based on that only im changing the description.

Comment: show your .cs code? and on which event you want that dropdowns values on their onchange(javascript)?? what does this function `GetCountryDetails()` ?

Comment: No..please ignore that onchange="GetCountryDetails()" event...want to get the all the values of dropdown in a row on changing the ddlShowTimingAMPM dropdown..that is by using dropdownslectedindexchange event.

Comment: I posted an answer try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 100% working and tested

Once you Find row then from that row you can find all Controls inside that row. You can same apply for other `DropDownList` and set  `AutoPostBack="true"` for all `DropDownList`

```
   protected void ddlShowTimingsHours_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridItem item = (DataGridItem)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.Parent;

        DropDownList ddlShowTimingsHours = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlShowTimingsHours");
        DropDownList ddlShowTimingsminutes= (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlShowTimingsminutes");
        DropDownList ddlShowTimingAMPM= (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlShowTimingAMPM");



    }
```